# Transferring Pictures and phone numbers

Tags: samsung

How do I remove pictures and emails from my Nokia android phone. And how do I copy my address book to my new Samsung Galaxy S5 phone?

Answer (score 0):

To transfer any file/picture/etc.. between your phone and PC, you'll need to turn Developer Options on and enable USB Debugging.

***Some Android devices already have Developer Options listed in the Settings menu. Most, however, need a certain "key combo" to bring it out of hiding***

1) On your phone, navigate to Settings 》About Device (Phone) 》and tap your device's Build Number 7 consecutive times. A caption will display at the bottom of your screen, stating how many taps are still needed & when you're considered a "Developer".

2) Once Developer Options is turned on, navigate back to Settings 》Developer Options 》and enable USB Debugging.

***Developer Options is located at the bottom of your Settings, above "About Phone"***

3) After enabling USB Debugging, plug your device to your PC via USB cable.

4) Swipe down the notification bar on your phone 》tap USB Options  》and verify your device is set at MTP. If it isn't, change it to MTP.

WALA! You are now able to swap files, pictures, etc.. from your phone to your PC and vice versa.

***Ensure proper connection between your phone and PC by clicking your PC's Start Menu, then navigating to the "Devices & Printers" section. Your phone will register as either an MTP Device or your phone's model number if properly connected. If not, it'll say a name you won't recognize and have a yellow triangle with an exclamation point (!) in the middle.***